# How to sort the results of filtering with django-filter in a ListAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a `ListAPIView` that uses the `DjangoFilterBackend` to filter rooms based on url parameters. The code below does this just fine.

Now, I would like to sort the results based on a score calculated from other attributes of the Room object, another url parameter, and possibly what we know about the user issuing the request. The function itself does not matter.

How can I sort the results after applying the filter I already have?

If I were to do the filtering myself, I suppose I could do the filtering, calculate the score and sort the results in the `get_queryset` but I do not know how to do this after the filtering with `django-filter`.

**Example query**

For example, I would do this query to filter by price lower than 100. The `other_field` value would be used to compute the score for sorting:

`http://localhost:8000/api/search/rooms?price=100&other_field=200`

**Code**

```
class RoomFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    price = filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_expr='lte')
    features = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        name="features", 
        conjoined=True,
        queryset=Features.objects.all()
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['price', 'features']

class RoomSearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSearchSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = RoomFilter
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to override `list()` in your API as below,

```
class RoomSearchView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Room.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoomSearchSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = RoomFilter

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        queryset = queryset.order_by('-id')  # change is here  >> sorted with reverse order of 'id'

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Excellent, it does exactly what I needed! I can then do whatever type of ordering there, including adding an extra score column. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in more flexible way with FilterSet class (RoomFilter in your case)

Define an **OrderFilter** with **fileds** keyword arguments in RoomFilter class

**fields** is a mapping of {model field name: parameter name}.

(https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html)

so you can do this:

```
class RoomFilter(filters.FilterSet):
price = filters.NumberFilter(name="price", lookup_expr='lte')
features = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    name="features", 
    conjoined=True,
    queryset=Features.objects.all()
    )

 o = OrderingFilter(
    fields=(
        ('id', 'id'),
        ('price', 'price'),
        # and any model field you want to sort based on
    )
)

class Meta:
    model = Room
    fields = ['price', 'features']
```

sort based on **id** and **ascending**:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/search/rooms?price=100&other_field=200&o=id
```

sort based on **id** and **descending**:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/search/rooms?price=100&other_field=200&o=-id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard sorting from Django REST:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter