# How to give priority to a certain field in SearchFilter fields in django rest framework?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views, query-string

I have a simple search api which search the db based on the query parameter provided to the search keyboard.

It works fine, but it has some issues.

For example, I have a category named Tv and home appliances. It has products like LG speakers and led tv. I have search query parameters for both category name and product name. When I search tv, speakers products are coming in the first page while tv products are coming in the 5th page which I don't want. It is because, category name has **Tv and Home**.

What I want is tv products to be appear in the first page while speakers to the other pages. For this I have to prioritise the product name field rather than category name.

How to do that?

```
{
 id:1
 category: TV and Home,
 product: 1500 W Speakers
}

{
 id:2
 category: Tv and Home,
 product: Led Tv 32"
}
```

I want id:2 to be appeared first then, the id:1, if I search with Tv.

```
class PrdouctSearchAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    print(queryset)
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter,OrderingFilter]    
    search_fields = ['name','brand__name','collection__name','sub_category__name',
                     'description','variants__color','category__name']
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

My local endpoint is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/productsearch?search=tv
```

My model:

```
class Product(models.Model):   
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150,unique=True
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this:

- Overriding the `list` method to `sort` the results before returning them (As mentionned in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060424/how-to-sort-the-results-of-filtering-with-django-filter-in-a-listapiview)).
- Overriding the `filter_queryset` directly

The idea is simply to add your sorting logic yourself after you've fetched the filtered data

Comment: Hello @Jordan, I went to your suggested link, what it has done is ordering by id. If I tried that with my product name, it will only order_by() product name in alphabetical order. It doesnt solve my issue. Can you please check.

Comment: A possible solution would be to sort your result list yourself, using `list.sort()`, by checking if the `product` field contains the searched text.